# How to create a subdomain for ircd?

Tags: subdomain, irc, cross-domain

If I have a working web site at example.com that runs with one hosting provider and wish to run ircd with another hosting provider, how would I set up subdomain irc.example.com for the server that runs that ircd?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704805/irc-subdomain-set-up

Comment: It is an exact duplicate, and there have been lots of similar questions recently. I'm pretty sure there's another exact duplicate question which I'm unable to find right now.

Answer (score 3):

Just add another `A` record to your DNS zonefile with the hostname and IP address you want to use